# Swift: get largest CGSize from array of objects comparing by height

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of objects called `personGalleryView.slideshowItems`

And I need to get the largest image `CGSize` compared it by height.

To get the first one entry `CGSize` I use `personGalleryView.slideshowItems.first?.imageView.image?.size`

But to get the largest one, not the first one I'm trying to use:

```
let maxSize = personGalleryView.slideshowItems
            .map { $0.imageView.image?.size }
            .max(by: { $0?.height < $1?.height })
```

But the compiler make error `Cannot convert value of type 'CGFloat?' to expected argument type 'Self'` on `$0?.height`

How to achieve this?

Anyway, Thank you!

Comment: If you're trying to find max dimensions you may use `.compactMap` instead of `.map`, and you won't have any problems with `Optional` comparasing.

Comment: One way is to put null-coalescing operator if you are comparing optionals. `$0?.height ?? 0 < $1?.height ?? 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using `.compactMap` since it removes the `nil` values therefore  you can use `.max` with no problems,

```
let maxSize = personGalleryView.slideshowItems
.compactMap { $0.imageView.image?.size }
.max(by: { $0.height < $1.height })
```

Comment: @MartinR Well a user had an answer, i discussed his answer as it would cause a crash, just was making a point, he deleted his answer then i got the downvote, i can't be sure if it was him

Comment: It’s actually, thanks for the heads up , I’ll edit, however usually in those cases an edit suggested rather than down vote

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190236/discussion-between-mohmmad-s-and-ielyamani).